# Issue with UPDATE in this MySQL Code to modify a song's release year?

Tags: mysql

The given SQL creates a Song table and inserts three songs.

Write three UPDATE statements to make the following changes:

Change the title from 'One' to 'With Or Without You'.
Change the artist from 'The Righteous Brothers' to 'Aritha Franklin'.

--I know they misspelled Aretha, that's not the problem

Change the release years of all songs after 1990 to 2021.

Run your solution and verify the songs in the result table reflect the changes above.

```
CREATE TABLE Song (
  ID INT,
  Title VARCHAR(60),
  Artist VARCHAR(60),
  ReleaseYear INT,
  PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);

INSERT INTO Song VALUES
  (100, 'Blinding Lights', 'The Weeknd', 2019),
  (200, 'One', 'U2', 1991),
  (300, 'You\'ve Lost That Lovin\' Feeling', 'The Righteous Brothers', 1964),
  (400, 'Johnny B. Goode', 'Chuck Berry', 1958);

-- Write your UPDATE statements here:
UPDATE Song
SET Title = 'With Or Without You' WHERE ID = 200;
UPDATE Song
SET Artist = 'Aritha Franklin' WHERE ID = 300;
UPDATE Song
SET ReleaseYear = 2021;

SELECT *
FROM Song;
```

It should be noted that the solution as is, works. I already got credit for this solution.
My issue comes towards the end, The assignment specifically wants songs released after 1990 to be changed to 2021 which would be ID's 100, 200. This solution changed everything to 2021.  I tried doing this...

```
SET ReleaseYear = 2021 WHERE ID = (100, 200);
```

But It freaks out because there are 2 operands. So then I tried

```
CREATE TABLE Song (
  ID INT,
  Title VARCHAR(60),
  Artist VARCHAR(60),
  ReleaseYear INT,
  PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);

INSERT INTO Song VALUES
  (100, 'Blinding Lights', 'The Weeknd', 2019),
  (200, 'One', 'U2', 1991),
  (300, 'You\'ve Lost That Lovin\' Feeling', 'The Righteous Brothers', 1964),
  (400, 'Johnny B. Goode', 'Chuck Berry', 1958);

-- Write your UPDATE statements here:
UPDATE Song
SET Title = 'With Or Without You' WHERE ID = 200;
UPDATE Song
SET Artist = 'Aritha Franklin' WHERE ID = 300;
ALTER TABLE Song
ADD CONSTRAINT ReleaseYearCheck CHECK (ReleaseYear >= 1990);
SET ReleaseYear = 2021;

SELECT *
FROM Song;
```

It fails the constraint check as I would expect. I have no idea how to change it to just specifically modify "Blinding Lights", and "With or Without You" to have a release year of 2021.
I can ONLY add code where it states "--Write your UPDATE statements here:".

Keep in mind the first code block which I already worked out, gives me credit for the question. I believe there is an error in the assignment checker thing, because the first code block changed everything's release year. Per the question, it would seem it only wants to see the ReleaseYear change for Blinding Lights, and With or Without You to 2021.

Comment: `ID = (100, 200)` in SQL is an expression `ID IN (100, 2000)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the criteria is above 1990:

```
UPDATE Song
SET ReleaseYear = 2021
WHERE ReleaseYear >= 1990
```

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me

CREATE TABLE Song (
ID INT,
Title VARCHAR(60),
Artist VARCHAR(60),
ReleaseYear INT,
PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);

INSERT INTO Song VALUES
(100, 'Blinding Lights', 'The Weeknd', 2019),
(200, 'One', 'U2', 1991),
(300, 'You've Lost That Lovin' Feeling', 'The Righteous Brothers', 1964),
(400, 'Johnny B. Goode', 'Chuck Berry', 1958);

-- Write your UPDATE statements here:
UPDATE Song
SET Title = 'With Or Without You'
WHERE Title = 'One';
UPDATE Song
SET Artist = 'Aretha Franklin'
Where ID = 300;
UPDATE Song
SET ReleaseYear = '2021'
WHERE ReleaseYear >1990;

SELECT *
FROM Song;